# Finding duplicate values in SQL including substrings

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a database of songs, and I want to find duplicates:

- With the exact same title, e.g. "itsy bitsy" vs "itsy bitsy"
- OR with one title the substring of the other, e.g. "itsy bitsy" vs "itsy bitsy spider"

I have tried using LIKE like this:

```
  scope :duplicate_titles, -> {
    where("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM songs AS songs1
                            WHERE songs1.title LIKE (songs.title || '%')) > 1")
  }
```

However it's very slow, queries that were 40ms jump to 2s with this LIKE statement.

Is there a better way to find duplicates, including where one field is the substring of another?

Edit 1: some examples

```
id: 1, title: "itsy bitsy spider"
id: 2, title: "itsy bitsy"
id: 3, title: "row, row, row your boat"
id: 4, title: "twinkle twinkle"
id: 5, title: "twinkle twinkle little star"
```

In this data, I would want to find songs 1,2,4,5 (or at least songs 2 and 4) because they are duplicates.

Edit 2: Another attempt

I tried using substring like this:

```
  scope :duplicate_titles, -> {
    where("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM songs AS songs1
                            WHERE SUBSTRING(songs1.title, 0, LENGTH(songs.title)+1) = songs.title) > 1")
  }
```

But this took even longer, 4.3s to execute a query..

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Here's the SQL you want: `select s.title, s.id from songs s join songs ss on strpos(s.title, ss.title) > 0 and s.id != ss.id;` (to get the "at least 2 and 4" result, add `ss.id and/or ss.title` to see the 1,2,4,5 results).

Comment: (1) Look at the EXPLAIN output for your queries and you'll probably see a Seq Scan (i.e. a table scan where the query will look at every single row in the table to check the LIKE. (2) Look at trigram indexes to improve LIKE's performance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/479863

Comment: Question : Would `itsy bitsy spider` and `the itsy bitsy spider` need to match?

Comment: @phatfingers for my current work (I can't post real data online) I don't need that, all duplications start the same, just some go on longer

Comment: @Mirror318 In that case, a simple index on `songs.title` would probably suffice without requiring any changes to your code.

Comment: One small caveat, though.  It doesn't respect word boundaries, so if you wanted to avoid matching "twinkle twin" to "twinkle twinkle", you'd need to refactor your approach.

Comment: @muistooshort thank you! I added a GIN index and that sped things up a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any `text` value directly as a POSIX regular expression and look for a case-insensitive match using [`~*` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE). If it's a substring or the same whole value, it'll match. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/w8pqrbpu)

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | itsy bitsy spider |
| 2 | itsy bitsy |
| 3 | itsy bitsy |
| 4 | row row row your boat |
| 5 | twinkle twinkle |
| 6 | twinkle twinkle little star |

```
select * from song s1 
inner join song s2 
 on s1.title ~* s2.title;
```

| id | title | id | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | itsy bitsy spider | 1 | itsy bitsy spider |
| 1 | itsy bitsy spider | 2 | itsy bitsy |
| 1 | itsy bitsy spider | 3 | itsy bitsy |
| 2 | itsy bitsy | 2 | itsy bitsy |
| 2 | itsy bitsy | 3 | itsy bitsy |
| 3 | itsy bitsy | 2 | itsy bitsy |
| 3 | itsy bitsy | 3 | itsy bitsy |
| 4 | row row row your boat | 4 | row row row your boat |
| 5 | twinkle twinkle | 5 | twinkle twinkle |
| 6 | twinkle twinkle little star | 5 | twinkle twinkle |
| 6 | twinkle twinkle little star | 6 | twinkle twinkle little star |

The operator is [supported by `pg_trgm` gin index since version 9.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-INDEX):

```sql
insert into song(title) select gen_random_uuid() from generate_series(1,1e4);
create extension pg_trgm;
create index idx_gin on song using gin(title gin_trgm_ops);

vacuum analyze song;

explain analyze verbose
select * from song s1 
inner join song s2 
 on s1.title ~* s2.title;
```

```
QUERY PLAN
Nested Loop  (cost=1.15..62954.79 rows=500600 width=72) (actual time=0.139..1348.324 rows=10011 loops=1)
  Output: s1.id, s1.title, s2.id, s2.title
  ->  Seq Scan on public.song s2  (cost=0.00..194.06 rows=10006 width=36) (actual time=0.008..2.999 rows=10006 loops=1)
        Output: s2.id, s2.title
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.song s1  (cost=1.15..5.77 rows=50 width=36) (actual time=0.131..0.132 rows=1 loops=10006)
        Output: s1.id, s1.title
        Recheck Cond: (s1.title ~* s2.title)
        Heap Blocks: exact=10006
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_gin  (cost=0.00..1.13 rows=50 width=0) (actual time=0.099..0.099 rows=1 loops=10006)
              Index Cond: (s1.title ~* s2.title)
Planning Time: 1.093 ms
Execution Time: 1349.713 ms
```

For more flexibility and performance you'd probably be interested in [Full Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html) rather than pattern matching: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/_oXF-9fz)

```sql
alter table song 
  add column title_tsv tsvector 
  generated always as (title::tsvector) stored;
create index idx_gin on song using gin(title_tsv);

vacuum analyze song;

explain analyze verbose
select * from song s1 
inner join song s2 
 on s1.title_tsv @@ plainto_tsquery(s2.title);
```

```
QUERY PLAN
Nested Loop  (cost=1.39..190546.32 rows=500600 width=168) (actual time=23.066..210.612 rows=11 loops=1)
  Output: s1.id, s1.title, s1.title_tsv, s2.id, s2.title, s2.title_tsv
  ->  Seq Scan on public.song s2  (cost=0.00..243.06 rows=10006 width=84) (actual time=0.011..2.054 rows=10006 loops=1)
        Output: s2.id, s2.title, s2.title_tsv
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.song s1  (cost=1.39..18.52 rows=50 width=84) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=0 loops=10006)
        Output: s1.id, s1.title, s1.title_tsv
        Recheck Cond: (s1.title_tsv @@ plainto_tsquery(s2.title))
        Heap Blocks: exact=6
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_gin  (cost=0.00..1.38 rows=50 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=10006)
              Index Cond: (s1.title_tsv @@ plainto_tsquery(s2.title))
Planning Time: 0.664 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 6
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 0.582 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 1.229 ms, Emission 19.922 ms, Total 21.733 ms
Execution Time: 365.554 ms
```

Comment: The regex will trigger table scans just like LIKE does.

Comment: @muistooshort I replaced the plain example of `~*` with one that uses `gin(title gin_trgm_ops)` index from `pg_trgm` to speed it up and added an actual example of the FTS, also backed by an index.

Comment: Thanks, I created a GIN index and that sped things up

Answer (score 0):

data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   id     INTEGER  NOT NULL  
  ,title  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
 
);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,title) VALUES (1,'itsy bitsy spider');
INSERT INTO mytable(id,title) VALUES (2,'itsy bitsy');
INSERT INTO mytable(id,title) VALUES (3,'row row row your boat');
INSERT INTO mytable(id,title) VALUES (4,'twinkle twinkle');
INSERT INTO mytable(id,title) VALUES (5,'twinkle twinkle little star');
```

use join on like

```
select * from mytable m1
join mytable m2
on  m1.title LIKE '%' || m2.title || '%'
and m1.id<>m2.id
```

or use contain  as follows

```
select * from mytable m1
join mytable m2
on  POSITION(m2.title IN m1.title)<>0
and m1.id<>m2.id
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/P04w5Zrk)

Comment: This will still include a table scan so it will be slow.